# Why i can't see created ACL into the distribution settings of cloud front?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have created an ACL. And it is also enabled.
And i want to associate with a cloud front distribution.

There are two problems
1. I do not see my ACL into the dropdown list of distribution settings either while creating new cloudfront or for previous cloudfronts. It remains `None` in the dropdown.[image]

2. in the WAF > Web ACLs > [my created ack] > Rules > AWS resources using this web ACL
   when i click on Add association, it does not show my already available cloudfronts. It rather has Recource dropdown disabled. and showing `No resources found` (resource type is fixed and non editable with `Application load balancer`)
   [image]

What is happening?

My goal is that a request will be passed through the cloudfront only if it is not catched in ACL of WAF.
Can i see a simple tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a Web ACL in WAF requires you to choose the type of ACL -- CloudFront or Application Load Balancer -- at the beginning of the process, but this selection is hiding under the dropdown labeled **`Region`**, which defaults to US East (N. Virginia) (a.k.a. us-east-1) **and this option implicitly selects an ALB WAF**.

[image: Screenshot of AWS WAF Console wizard showing Region dropdown]

This is unfortunate UI design, since what is offered as the default also seems like the correct choice.

Why would us-east-1 be the intuitive choice?  Because CloudFront is a global (not regional) service, and its home region is us-east-1.  (That's why [us-east-1 is the correct region to select in Amazon Certificate Manager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-regions.html) when you want to use an ACM certificate with CloudFront.)

But WAF does things a little differently.  In (I suspect) an attempt to make it easier, they've actually made it less so.  You'll need to go back and create a new Web ACL, selecting `Global (CloudFront)` for the region.

Comment: This should be the marked answer, and I'm very thankful it exists. I was actually stuck and Google'd for it. :) I agree that this UI could be better. I saw the "correct" region selected and just glossed over that setting entirely. I'll file the feedback with the appropriate service team and point them over to this post.